Weeding out bad tags initiative 2014
During the process of burninating [tag:software], I found other ill-defined tags. I have collected them for us to tackle together. It's time to sort out this tagging mess. Let's get this started.

What are good tags?

Does the tag add valuable information when it is added to a question?
Can the tag be the only tag of a question?
Does the tag commonly mean the same thing for different people?
Does the tag create a specific, well-defined category?
Can you see anyone at some point subscribing to the tag or searching for related questions by using the tag?
Can you see anyone using this tag to ignore a topic?
Is there a very similar tag that is more popular which could be applied instead?

If a tag's usefulness is contested, think about whether its name or definition could be improved and rather err on allowing it.

Tagging-Guide
Applying that logic, some examples for good and bad tags:

Software tags – GOOD

multibit
bitcoind
cgminer

Service tags – GOOD

bitstamp
coinbase
blockchain.info

Altcoin tags – GOOD

dogecoin
litecoin
auroracoin

Cryptocurrency specific terms – GOOD

difficulty
mining
block

Tags that describe the question, not the content – BAD

best-practices
definition
opinion

Tags that mean different things in different topics – BAD

earnings
data-quantity
computing

Tags that could be used on (almost) any question – BAD

usage
workings
comparison

Tags that are off-topic – BAD

hosting
sd-card
ip



How to help?
Pick a tag that you are familiar with and look through questions tagged with it. Fix the whole question, also fix:

grammar errors
bad titles
remove inappropriate tags
add tags that should be on the question.

Anyone can suggest edits! Feel free to join us in the Bitcoin Lounge. :)
If you feel that a tag on this list should rather be kept unchanged, move it to the disputed section, and post an answer why it should stay.

Tags to be evaluated and processed
alternative-blockchains
alternatives
amazon
build
compiling
control
conversion
crypto-2.0
crypto-currencies
deterministic
development
diskspace
dns
donation
earnings
education
electricity
encoding
error
exploitation
export
formatting
forum
fragmentation
future
governance
hacking
hash
hashing
hashpower
hosting
hybrid
identity
incentive
installation
installing
irc
job
ledger
library
license
limit
linode
live-data
local
logging
loss
lost-transactions
market
market-depth
marketplace
media
mining-pools
novelty
oracle
orphaned-block
ownership
packets
people
performance
phishing
politics
portable
power
probability
race
random
restore
retail
reward
rsa
safemode
search
security-key
services
shops
speed
spending
stability
stale-block
standardization
stocks
streaming
support
terms
ticker
trade
travel
uk
uri
usa
value
value-add
video
virtual-currency
visa
volume
voting
warmstorage
website-development
websites
wiki
wikileaks
wireless
I previously had my preliminary notes in the above list, but that made it completely unreadable, so I moved it to this >> tag overview table.

Tags to delete
Don't just delete the tag from the question and ignore everything else.
If a question also has grammatical errors, terrible title, et cetera, then fix that along with removing the tag. 

Tags to fix
Either these tags have been re-defined or were being used inconsistently. Questions marked with this tag need to be checked and retagged accordingly. When a tag from this category has been cleaned, please add it to the Fixed section at the bottom, so no one else spends time on them.
accounts
altcoin
lost

Disputed Tags

Cleaned
Burninated
academic
best-practices
bug
calculations
command-line
communication
companies
comparison
competitor
computing
configuration
crash
custom
data-quantity
debug
definition
delivery
design
files
generation
gui
idea
innovation
international
ip
list
maths
measurements
mistake
monitoring
morality
non-standard
notation
opinion
person
read-only
reference
release
resilience
resources
sd-card
software
source-code
start
statistics
upgrade
usage
version
wireless
write-protect
workings
Merged 

debit → debitcard
download → synchronization
error-detection → security
gateway → ripple-gateways
halving → reward-schedule
graphs → charts
jargon → terminology
notation → terminology
science → academic-research
resilience → weaknesses
stability → price-volatility
terms → terminology
vocabulary → terminology
volatility → price-volatility
vulnerability → security

Fixed 


Hmm, that shiny new diamond looking thing next to your name might help a bit with this ;)

Cool. :D I'll see that I get on to it a bit later today, once I get home from work and get a handle on all this new information I am seeing. ;)

@fredsbend: Don't miss the "tag overview table" which gives some reasons and thoughts about why some things are bad.

Please use the format 
tag – Offense (reason to be deleted)
For any tags that aren't obvious perpetrators, please open a new post and link them here.
Candidates for Burninating

software – meta tag
usage – Unfocused
alternatives – Unfocussed

Ongoing discussions

code, source, source-code, development – This discussion doesn't seem to be resolved yet: Discussion here
configuration – Should be removed as a meta-tag?

Comments on how some tags might be handled

upgrade – Delete,  seems to be a meta tag. –Murch
comparison – Not well-defined and specific enough. Should be removed. –Discussion between @DavidPerry, @Murch
altcoin – needs an in-depth discussion –Discussion between @JacobTorba, @DavidPerry, @Murch
datacoind – Synonym of bitcoind? –Murch
data-quantity – Meta tag? –Murch
ddos – Merge into attack? –Murch
debug – Not specific, well-defined category, remove? –Murch
definition – Not specific, well-defined category, remove? –Murch
delivery – Refers to questions concerning delayed mining equipment. Off-topic? –Murch
design – Domain should be clarified –Murch
deterministic – Should perhaps be changed to deterministic-wallet –Murch
diskspace – Should be defined as diskspace used by the blockchain specifically, but then would be covered by blockchain? –Murch
dns – It isn't clear how this tag refers to Bitcoin. –Murch
donation – ranges from charities to legal –Murch
download – seems to be a duplicate of synchronization –Murch
earnings – Unfocused: Refering to "earning bitcoins", "profitability" and making money through trading
education – Unclear: Referring to university and educating new users.
electricity – Unfocused: Referring to Cost of mining, power-surges, and power requirements of ASIC
encoding – Should get a tag description at least.
exploitation – Duplicate of attack?
export – Should be specified, perhaps to "private-key-export"
files – Meta-Tag?
formatting – Unfocussed.
forum – Off-topic?
fragmentation – Seems to refer to "Coin selection" and "splitting of outputs", not sure if it is useful.
future – Seems to collect questions concerned with things that may still come to pass, and futures contracts.
generation – Just no distinction at all: Bitcoin generation, transaction generation... Should be deleted.
novelty, academic, alternative-blockchains, alternatives, 
amazon, best-practices, bug, build, command-line, communication, companies, compiling, computing, control, conversion, crash, crypto-currencies, custom,...

list to be continued starting from "E".
DONE

idea,innovation – both together just on one question, describing something previously known. Just removed them. ;) -> DONE.
error-detection – Replaced with security in the one instance it was on a question. -> DONE.
article – Should be merged into the encompassing news –Discussion between @DavidPerry, @Murch -> DONE.
competitor – "that one just needs to get burned" –@DavidPerry --- manually edited -> DONE.
charts&graphs – Should be merged perhaps? --> merged as proposed.
debit – Merge into debitcard –Murch --> merged
gateway – Seems to be a duplicate of ripple-gateways --> merged


I would like Transaction-Maliability and Tx-ID to be merged and or an alias created.

@makerofthings7 See: http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/521/5406

Suggestion: Merge miner into mining.

[miner] and [mining] have been merged.
